# How to insert site preview image for Facebook AND WhatsApp simultaneously?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, meta

I know how to use Open Graph meta tags in head of HTML. Example:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://sitename.com/">
<meta property="og:title" content="My blog"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Tutorial..."/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://sitename.com/img/tutorial.png"/>
```

But if a type of preview image is good for WhatsApp, it's not good for Facebook! So how should you set meta tags for different platforms at the same time? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify two (or more) Open Graph images, the first, a rectangular image for FB and the second, a square image for WhatsApp.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://sitename.com/">
<meta property="og:title" content="My blog"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Tutorial..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sitename.com/img/tutorial_1200-600.png"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sitename.com/img/tutorial_400-400.png"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400"/>
```

WhatsApp uses the last image.

Comment: @qqq is correct – you want to add Open Graph tags to your website. If you’re targeting WhatsApp, you should include two images, a 1200x640 followed by a 400x400. WhatsApp likes a square image while other sites (e.g. Facebook) will use a rectangular image. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512739/how-to-insert-site-preview-image-for-facebook-and-whatsapp-simultaneously/